# how to pass config file to flask startup command to zappa

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I am using python flask and using below command to start flask app but how do i pass this to zappa for aws lambda deployment.

```
python abc.py config/config.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Zappa supports [remote config](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#remote-environment-variables-via-an-s3-file) that you can create the configuration file and place it in an S3 bucket to which your Zappa application has access.

zappa_settings.json:

```
{
    "dev": {
        ...
        "remote_env": "s3://my-config-bucket/config.json",
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: my app running with this python `abc.py config/config.py`  command what do i change in zappa which will run this command to start my flask app